# Translate values dict-like in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Model I define choices along the lines of:

```
LANG_CHOICES = (
    ("Englisch", (
        (u"en-gb", u"England"),
        (u"en-us", u"United States of America"),
    ), )
```

The field is defined as:

```
lang_source = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=LANG_CHOICES, default="en-gb")
```

Naturally, in my template I'd want to display the human-readable value, i.e.

```
{{ object.lang_source }}
```

should not print "en-gb" (or the respective value) but rather "England".

What is the most elegant way to accomplish this? (Besides in the View importing a dict from the Model and manually translating the value.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
object.get_lang__source_display()
```

Documentation:

- http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Answer (score 1):

http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/

```
{{ object.get_lang_source_display }}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using two underscores in a row when defining field name is forbidden, because of the way django filters QuerySets: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-restrictions

Comment: That was just a typo due to the way SO funky-formats special characters.